# QComboBox AbstractItemView::item

Tags: qt, qt4, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

Is there a way I could increase the height of the items, which are listed in a QComboBox control ?

I tried following as suggested here [in QTDevNet forums](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3474) but with no luck

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item {margin-top: 3px;}
```

I also tried this, still with no result.

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item {min-height: 20px;}
```

Is it possible to achieve this at style-sheet level at all ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your style sheet seemed correct, so I tried it. It seems the problem is similar to [this one on Qt centre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/39268-Styling-a-QAbstractItemView-item):

> `QCompleter` sets a custom `QAbstractItemDelegate` on its model and unfortunately this custom item delegate does not inherit `QStyledItemDelegate` but simply `QItemDelegate` (and then overrides the `paint` method to show the selected state).

If you replace the default delegate by a `QStyledItemDelegate`, your style sheet should work:

```
QStyledItemDelegate* itemDelegate = new QStyledItemDelegate();
combo->setItemDelegate(itemDelegate);
```

**Important:** If you change the model, then that will reset the view's delegate, so the above method needs to be called after any call to `setModel()`.

Comment: seems this is the least painful way to implement my requirement, thank you

Comment: For me, it still doesn't work. I did what you say, and tried to use the same style, and it doesn't work.Stays in the same way.

Comment: for anyone like @darkgaze still having an issue after using this solution, try using the `QComboBox ::item` as your selector within the style sheet. This answer along with that selector worked for me.

Comment: This helped me - thanks and +1!  The referenced article says that this must be done after any call to `setModel()` - if true, that's really worth mentioning here.

Comment: Another suggestion: If the height of items in the view is not working, try to add items from `cpp` after `setItemDelegate`. I ran into a stylesheet problem when adding items from QtDesigner.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative [solution](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/21707-QcomboBox-item-height) would be:

`ui->comboBox->model()->setData(ui->comboBox->model()->index(-row-, 0), QSize(-width-, -height-), Qt::SizeHintRole);`

, where `-row-` is zero-based item index; `-width-` and `-height-` stand for item width hint and height hint, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`QComboBox::item` worked for me

So for example, I was trying to change the color of the item when it was disabled, and the following code did the trick.

This one did not work:

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:!enabled {
    color:red;
}
```

Instead I used:

```
QComboBox::item:!enabled {
    color:red;
}
```