# QLineEdit`s QCompleter stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qcompleter

Having a `QLineEdit` with a plain vanilla `QStringList` `QCompleter`. I wonder if I can change the appearance of the dropdown (I want to have either a min. size or smaller scrollbar).

[image: QCompleter]

Clarification: I want to set it in a stylesheet, not in the code.

Summary of my findings so far:

1. Pretty good summary here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/26703/solved-stylize-using-css-and-editable-qcombobox-s-completions-list-view/12
2. I have to use `QStyledItemDelegate` and
3. give the popup a name for the qss selector
4. I have tried that and it does not work for me, but seems to work for others

Comment: Obviously I have to set a `QStyledItemDelegate` as said here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13313676/356726

Answer (score 4):

A simple straight forward solution is to set the stylesheet of the `QScrollBar` used by the `popup` of the `QCompleter`. My knowledge of qss is little, so I don't know if you can set a minimum size that way, but you can always have a look at [`verticalScrollBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#verticalScrollBar).

Here is some code for the qss way:

```
#include <QAbstractItemView>
#include <QCompleter>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLineEdit edit;
    edit.show();

    QStringList completionList;
    for (int a = 0 ; a < 10 ; ++a) {
        completionList << QString("test%1").arg(a);
    }

    QCompleter completer(completionList);

    edit.setCompleter(&completer);

    QAbstractItemView *popup = completer.popup();

    popup->setStyleSheet("QScrollBar{ width: 50px;}");

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: that`s useful but I would like to avoid to have it hardcoded. So I need to find the qss selectors, but your code has given me some ideas to tryout -> upvoted.

Comment: Hi! Can i ask that what was the correct soluton with the QSS selectors? I would like to do that too, but with an external QSS file. Ty for your answer! :)