# How to remove the arrow from a QCombobox popup?

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet

I have a QComboBox that shows a selection arrow by default on the left when clicked - snapshot attached below.

[image]

My stylesheet is as below

```
#define PROFILE_PAGE_COMBOBOX_CSS_ACTIVE " \
    QComboBox { \
        background:white; \
        border:1px solid gray \
    } \
    QComboBox::down-arrow { \
        image: url(:/images/profilecomboboxdropdown.png); width:15px; height: 15px; \
    } \
    QComboBox::drop-down { \
        subcontrol-origin: padding; \
        subcontrol-position: right; \
        width: 15px; \
        height: 15px; \
        border:0px; \
        padding-right:8px; \
    } \
    QComboBox QAbstractItemView { \
        border: 0px; \
        padding: 1px; \
        background-color: #ffffff; \
        color: gray; \
        selection-background-color: #ffffff; \
        selection-color: blue; \
    } \
"

this->m_CountryEdit->setStyleSheet(PROFILE_PAGE_COMBOBOX_CSS_ACTIVE);
```

How can I get rid of this selection arrow? I am using Qt 4.7.4 on both Mac and Windows

Comment: This looks unusual. Which style are you using?

Comment: I have the exact same problem and I haven't found a solution to it yet

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: I am not knowingly setting any specific style.

Comment: Which version of Qt and which OS are you using? Can't reproduce this problem. Perhaps, there is other stylesheet that adds the arrow.

Comment: @york.beta - I am using Qt 4.7.4 on a Mac as well as Windows - updated the question with this info. The arrow appears on both the OSs.

Comment: @york.beta: No, there is not any other stylesheet interfering since I tested on a new and fresh project

Comment: What is version of Windows? I tested on Windows 8 and Qt 4.8.

Comment: I'll try this code on Windows 7 soon. Perhaps I couldn't reproduce this issue, because I tested it using Preview in Qt Designer, but not a test application.

Comment: Windows 7, Qt 4.7.3, compiler MS Visual Studio 2010: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ReGJK5y.png)

Comment: May be this is due to css you are using, or javascript you are using. Can you write your complete css and aspx(or html) code here?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417038/qcombobox-drop-down-list-set-selected-item-style

Answer (score 0):

It's a mac-specific issue and there sseems to be several ways to live with it
- make selection mark to go offscreen with stylesheet positioning
- make it look less ugly by removing the border around (it's a question of removing a style that makes that border to show)
- so not set 'surrent' item in combobox probably

Comment: "make selection mark to go offscreen" - Can you share an example code?